# Can't figure out why my carousel is not working (Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to learn bootstrap and I have turned to the awesome creators on YouTube for help with that and copying their code to try and figure out what each individual element does. One problem, after copying the code exactly, I can't seem to figure out why this carousel is not swapping slides automatically (I don't need any controls). If anyone could shed some light that would be amazing.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/computerroom.png" alt="computer room" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/owenscomputerrepair.png" alt="owens computer repair" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value via the data-interval attribute to tell it how often to cycle automatically as specified in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery & bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 0):

The two items need to be inside `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You have two divs with the `carousel-inner` class.  There should only be one, and both your items should be inside that.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="computer room" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="owens computer repair" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```